# ng-click not working within bootstrapped ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

i've an ng-include bootstrapped actually

```
<a data-href="#/speakers/{{speaker.id}}" ng-click="myFunc('{{speaker.id}}')">
    <span class="speaker-name">{{speaker.name}}</span>
    <span class="speaker-title-company">{{speaker.title}}, {{speaker.company}}</span>
</a>
```

`ng-include` is

```
<ng-include id="speakers" data-ng-controller="SpeakerController" src="'js/view/partials/speakers.html'" ng-show="toggle"></ng-include>
```

boostrapping

```
var self = this;

angular.module(this.constructor.NAME, [])
.controller("SpeakerController", function($scope, $location){self.speakerController($scope, $location)})
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("speakers"), [this.constructor.NAME]);
```

and then the speakerController

```
speakerController: function($scope, $location) {
    var self = this;

    $scope.myFunc = function(param){console.log('in');self.myFunc(param)}
},

myFunc: function(param) {
    console.log(param);  
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to `ng-click="myFunc(speaker.id)"`. You don't need to use an expression there.

Comment: awesome, how can I pass the `data-href="#/speakers/{{speaker.id}}"`  basically the url to myFunc(url) function, the links would be like #/speakers/1, #/speakers/2, #/speakers/3 etc. or what's the best way this works in angular world, I'm forced to use `window.location=url` for some reason in the code

Comment: I suggest that you pass the variable as is, and append the static part within the function. But if you insist, `ng-click="MyFunc('#/speakers/' + speaker.id)"`

Comment: I looked up, $event.target, but then the problem is, the href is on the parent element, and $event.target is the `<span>` tag in my case, but I've hg-click setup in my anchor, is there something like $this? so I pass the anchor itself with the $event and getAttribute('data-href') from the anchor ($this), cause there could be more attrs defined at anchor

Comment: I don't know where this `$event.$target` is, but at any rate this sounds like a different question that you should post.